# What kind of a hand saw guide is being used in this video?

Tags: hand-tools, hand-saw, tool-identification, miter-saw

[image]

<sup>Image from [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRFnY0Xcogo&t=90)</sup>

[Go to about 1:30 in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRFnY0Xcogo&t=90) to see the saw guide.

I am helping my son build a pinewood derby car, and something like this would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the specific make of that guide but it is known as a [hand mitre saw](https://www.google.com/search?q=hand+mitre+saw&tbm=isch).

For example, from [here](http://filter--blog.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-hand-mitre-box-that-never-wears.html?m=1):

[image]

(The one in that image appears to resemble a vintage Stanley mitre box, maybe a Stanley 358.)

There are other styles of mitre guides and boxes, too, the most familiar probably being the little plastic box with angled slots in the sides.

Comment: Still keeping an eye out for a used "classic" miter saw. New ones are still sold, but are a bit pricy and so are farther back on the queue.

Comment: @keshlam, yard sales, antique/flea markets, and estate sales are probably your best bet for a decently-priced miter box.

Comment: Unfortunately, most yard sales that admit to having tools have the good stuff snapped up the moment they open, if not days ewarlier when they first announce...

Comment: @keshlam There's a [358 on eBay right now](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Antique-Stanley-Miter-Saw-no-358-with-Disston-Saw-/141869886054) if you're interested, just posted a few hours ago. Lots of time for the price to go up and probably needs some work but maybe worth watching? You can also follow ebay search results and receive notifications when new listings come up.